# Gaming Questions of the Week #4

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, blog, question-of-the-week

In an effort to try and keep the Question of the Week going, please submit your suggestions for this week!

### Sample Questions:

- First week's question - [Minecraft's World Size](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/minecrafts-world-size)
- Second weeks question - [Pokemon Missingno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19638/10)
- Last week's top answer - [Optimum Mazing Path (by Length)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/optimum-mazing-path-by-length)
- Suggestions:

  - [Where is there “impossible geometry” in Portal 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20601/10)
  - [Does GLaDOS say anything meaningful when she “gives us the fast version” in Test Area 8?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/does-glados-say-anything-meaningful-when-she-gives-us-the-fast-version-in-test)
  - [Portal 2's Turret Symphony Song and Lyrics?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/portal-2s-turret-symphony-song-and-lyrics)

If you want to nominate either of the two sample questions for this week, post them as an answer. Feel free to nominate any questions (or answers) you feel are deserve it as well!

Comment: @Grace Note: [status-completed](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/qotw/does-glados-hate-atlas-the-blue-robot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a pretty good one: [Does GLaDOS hate Atlas, the Blue Robot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20540/3015). The answers are pretty in depth and it features a recently released game.

Comment: I haven't actually looked at any Portal 2 questions because I'm trying to remain spoiler free until I do end up getting it.  So whatever Portal 2 question we pick, let's try to make sure that we warn people if there will be spoilers in the article.